# How to hide feedback button in the toolbar?

Tags: ios, aviary

How to hide the feedback button in the `Aviary` toolbar using `Objective C`?

Comment: Aviary have put so much effort to create SDK, if you want to hide feedback button support them by buying the premium version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the short answer will be "Purchase a white label package for $275/month".
This link clearly shows that "White label" option doesn't have a feedback button (along with any Aviary branding): http://developers.aviary.com/upgrades

Another option will be disassembling the Aviary code and removing feedback button by hand (which is not a trivial thing to do and you still wouldn't be able to publish the app on the App Store).